# Codeigniter 4 Unable to connect to the database on server?

Tags: mysql, codeigniter-4

I am working in CI 4 version. It's working fine on local server but when i uploaded it on server then i am getting error **Unable to connect to the database.
**.

This is my connection code in database.php

```
public $default = [
    'DSN'      => '',
    'hostname' => 'test.mysql.database.test.com',
    'username' => 'testusername',
    'password' => 'testpassword',
    'database' => 'testdb',
    'DBDriver' => 'MySQLi',
    'DBPrefix' => '',
    'pConnect' => false,
    'DBDebug'  => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'DBCollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swapPre'  => '',
    'encrypt'  => array(
                'ssl_ca' =>'',
                'ssl_verify' =>FALSE),
    'compress' => false,
    'strictOn' => false,
    'failover' => [],
    'port'     => 3306,
    
];
```

Please help me. I am not getting what's the issue as it's working on local server.
This is code in .env file

```
database.default.hostname = test.mysql.database.test.com
database.default.database = testdb
database.default.username = testusername
database.default.password = testpassword
database.default.DBDriver = MySQLi
database.default.encrypt.ssl_verify = true
database.default.encrypt.ssl_ca = './etc/certs/test.pem'
```

Comment: Is Codeigniter on the same host as the DB? Are you connecting from "the server" to a local Mysql service there, or the mysql service is on a foreign host?

Comment: codeigniter is on same host but db is on diff. host. No db is on server

Comment: So then why not use  `database.default.hostname = 127.0.0.1` ? or `localhost` ?

Comment: sorry db is on diff. host.  i am using 2 database here one is common database which have users data and  using for  login in panel. Another one is  to show data in admin panel

Comment: So from your server can you reach port 3306 (assuming this is the port for mysql) on the DB server? `telnet server_host_or_ip 3306` ? if not it might be a simple firewall issue on the DB server?

Comment: database port is 3306 alreday. I have connected db in sqlyog

Comment: sqlyog connects from your workstation. Since you cannot connect the SERVER where Codeigniter is, to the DB host, you need to test the connectivity between those two!

Comment: it's connecting, i have checked

Comment: and on the DB server you have `testusername@%` and not only `testusername@localhost` ? You should troubleshoot first outside your PHP app... from Server you should try `mysql -h test.mysql.database.test.com -u testusername -p` then enter your password... if that works then your connectivity is OK, and the issue is within Codeigniter or PHP... if you cannot connect, then it's mysql permissions

Comment: one more thing i have used same db connectivity with CI version 3 and it's working fine on server

Comment: i have tested it with simple php connection file and it's connected but in codeigniter not working

Comment: can anyone please help i have done a lot of R&D but did not get any solution

Answer (score 1):

Finally, it's working now. I have tried to connect it with core php and then with PDO. It was not working with mysqli and with pdo it's connected. So,on server mysqli extension was not enabled. After enable this it works.